# C++11 STL containers and thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, c++11

I have trouble finding any up-to-date information on this.

Do C++11 versions of STL containers have some level of thread safety guaranteed?

I do expect that they don't, due to performance reasons. But then again, that's why we have both [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) and [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).

Comment: My guess is, that bounds checking is on a totally different performance scale than mutexes or the like. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Thread safety at the level of container access is often useless as you want to write things like "cash[i] = cash[i] + total" and the locking needs to be at a higher level than on the container itsself.

Comment: A related question [Safe parallel read-only access to a STL container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833512/safe-parallel-read-only-access-to-a-stl-container?rq=1)

Comment: There are quite a few guarantees (sections [res.on.data.races], [container.requirements.dataraces] and of course the prerequisite [intro.multithread]). @Mr.C64's answer is very much to the point, if you want a more specific answer (possibly with standard quotes), please adjust the question.

Comment: @avakar It would be great if you could make an answer for quotes. I have the standard, but It would be nice to close the question an exhaustive answer.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since the existing answers don't cover it (only a comment does), I'll just mention 23.2.2 [container.requirements.dataraces] of the current [C++ standard specification](http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) which says:

> implementations are required to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in different elements in the same sequence, excepting `vector<bool>`, are modified concurrently.

i.e. it's safe to access distinct elements of the same container, so for example you can have a global `std::vector<std::future<int>>` of ten elements and have ten threads which each write to a different element of the vector.

Apart from that, the same rules apply to containers as for the rest of the standard library (see 17.6.5.9 [res.on.data.races]), as [Mr.C64's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931932/981959) says, and additionally [container.requirements.dataraces] lists some non-const member functions of containers that can be called safely because they only return non-const references to elements, they don't actually modify anything (in general any non-const member function must be considered a modification.)

Answer (score 32):

I think STL containers offer the following basic thread-safety guarantee:

- *simultaneous reads* of the *same* object are OK
- *simultaneous read/writes* of *different* objects are OK

But you have to use some form of custom synchronization (e.g. critical section) if you want to do something different, like e.g. simultaneous writes on the same object.

Comment: What is the meaning of "object" in this context? Element or container?

Comment: For example, is it OK to execute `myvec[0] = 0` and `myvec[1]` "simultaneously" in different threads? If the "object" is the container then that's a read and a write to the same object, but if the "object" is the element then it isn't. You can also imagine a container like a splay tree in which simultaneous reads to the container are not OK, but presumably if there's a guarantee that simultaneous reads are OK then it is forbidden for `std::map` to be implemented as a splay tree that's unsafe in that respect.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: "object" == container in this case.

Comment: @SteveJessop,  `myvec[0] = 0` while simultaneously `myvec[1]` is OK -- `operator[]` on sequential containers must avoid races ([container.requirements.dataraces]/1). This is not true for unordered and associative containers.

Comment: @avakar, I believe that requirement applies to all standard containers, not just the sequence containers. I'll request a new issue to clarify the wording.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I'm basing this on n3337/23.2.2/1: "For purposes of avoiding data races (17.6.5.9), implementations shall consider the following functions to be const: begin, end, [...] and, except in associative or unordered associative containers, operator[]."

Comment: @JonathanWakely, if you already have a valid pointer/reference to the elements, you can read them simultaneously. The data race could occur in the invocation of `[]` on the same container.

Comment: @avakar, Ah, sorry, I thought you meant §2 where it says "sequence", I think _that_ requirement applies to all containers. If you already have a valid reference to the elements you can **write** to them simultaneously iff they're different elements.

Answer (score -6):

No. Check out PPL or Intel TBB for thread safe STL-like containers.

Like others have noted they have usual "multiple reader thread safety" but that is even pre C++11. Ofc this doesnt mean single writer multiple readers. It means 0 writers. :)

Comment: "but that is even pre C++11" No it isn't. C++03 doesn't even know what threading *is*. So it does not specify behavior dealing with threading.

Comment: He didn't ask how compilers implement the standard. He what *guarantees* the *standard* provided; "guarantees" that implementations provide are therefore *irrelevant*.

Comment: that is your opinion, OP doesnt specifies that he is interested in just the standard and not reality.  But it is pointless discussion since first 2 chars of my answer are the most important part. Rest of the importance mostly lies in second sentence. :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl And in fact those *"first 2 chars"* that *"are the most important part"* are wrong, since the other answers have clearly shown that the there is indeed some level of thread-safety guaranteed, be it only for simultaneous reads without any writes, or certain functions. So a definite *"No"* is just too general to be correct in any way.

Comment: I dont consider that multiple readers is noteworthy(though I added that long time before ppl complained in the comments so that ppl dont get confused). Then again maybe Im not like average dev( In a sense that I see read safety as trivial - see my first comment)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: "*I dont consider that multiple readers is noteworthy*" But he didn't ask what *you* considered noteworthy. He asked for facts: "Do C++11 versions of STL containers have some level of thread safety guaranteed?" The factual answer is "Yes," because the standard does have *some level* of guarantees.

Comment: Seeing the downvotes, I am reminded of what I read somewhere about Courts' passing judgements: `We can't interpret what was on the minds of legislators. We only go by the letter of the law`. Seems to be a question of what was in the OP's mind when he asked about `some level of thread safety`