# Does a single queue with separate reader and writer threads needs locking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, readerwriterlock

I have a shared queue  (implemented using a singleton queue wrapper) and a reader thread and a writer thread. I also have a mechanism to inform the reader thread when writer thread adds elements (enqueue) to the queue. Reader thread dequeue only one element when informed. Is there a necessity of a Read Write Lock in this scenario.

Since writer is only enqueing and reader dequeing I feel like there is no need for a lock, if reader checks the queue size when dequeing.

Comment: What the heck is up with singletons today?

Comment: need more detail, so far best I can offer is "maybe"

Comment: You almost certainly do need a lock. But as Jasen mentions, more detail (ie., code) would be good so that more specific comments can be given.

Comment: writer thread notifies the reader for each insert and reader reads only one element upon notification. right?

Comment: yes. I will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since writer is only enqueing and reader dequeing I feel like there is no need for a lock, **if reader checks the queue size** when dequeing.

Among other problems that operation alone is already unsafe, when the queue is modified by another thread. In c++, any unsynchronized access to a non-atomic shared variable (with at least one of them is a write) is a data race and hence UB.

Comment: Why the downvote? Anything wrong with my answer? Or just not elaborate enough?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a stl::queue and **no** most operations on stl containers are not thread save. For an discussion on exceptions see [C++11 STL containers and thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931787/c11-stl-containers-and-thread-safety). STL prefers speed over security (e.g. range check for array indices etc.) assuming that developers will implement their own checks.