# std::list::insert thread safety

Tags: c++, thread-safety, std

Supposing all the operation I can do is either:

- Inserting new element into an std::list (or)
- Reading the back() element of the list

Am I thread safe? Any thread can do any of the two operations in any order. I'm not expecting any specific order to see, for eg if I insert an element and then read the back() I am NOT expecting it to be the last one I just inserted, all I need is that the returned element shall be a valid one.

Can I safely do this without introducing an undefined behavior?
Also I know I may need to use a concurrent queue, that's an option too I may consider, but this time I'm purely curious about this specific case with an std::list.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931787/c11-stl-containers-and-thread-safety . For your concrete list-insertion-case: No, you cannot expect thread-safety here since it's a container-distinct operation, not an element-distinct one.

Comment: That link is rather narrowing the scope of only accessing the elements, which is not necessarily the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I thread safe?

Potentially yes; Not necessarily.

It is crucial **where** the element is inserted. If you insert to the back of the list, then you have a data race, and therefore UB. If you insert elsewhere other than the end (and therefore the list must be non-empty prior to insert), then it should be thread safe.