# Communication between threads via shared vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, vector

I am designing a tcp server which takes information from a request and puts everything in a queue to be processed.  I am using a asio web server to handle all web interaction.  I am looking for an effective way to queue everything up to be processes.  I am using boost signals and global vector to do this right now similar to this.

```
void request_handler::handle_request(request &req, reply &rep)
{
   std::string parsedInfo = parse_request(req); 
   shared_queue.push_back(parsedInfo);
   new_entry();
}
```

new_entry is a boost signal

```
    boost::signal<void ()> new_entry;
```

Right now I have a signal handler class to catch the signal.

```
void sig_handler::process_next()
{
    boost::try_mutex::scoped_try_lock lock(guard);
    if(!lock)
       return;
    while(!shared_queue.empty())
    {
        ... //Do Stuff
        std::string cur_entry = shared_queue.at(0);
        shared_queue.erase(shared_queue.begin());
        ... //Do more stuff
    } 
}
```

My goal is to clear out the vector queue when there is information in it, and every time something is pushed on the vector.  I would like to avoid polling as much as possible.  I believe this part is working how I expect it too.  However I am getting an occasional crash from, what I believe based on my backtrace, pushing information on the shared queue.  This is only happening when I trying to do 1000's of transactions a second, which makes it hard to debug in a multi-threaded environment.  My back trace is here:

```
Error: signal 11:
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_Z7handleri+0x18)[0x469f68]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364a0)[0x7fbbdd67a4a0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsC1ERKSs+0xb)[0x7fbbddfb4f2b]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer[0x4749d0]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZNSt6vectorISsSaISsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsS1_EERKSs+0x111)[0x476521]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZN15request_handler14handle_requestERK7requestR5reply+0x3d3)[0x475873]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZN10connection11handle_readERKN5boost6system10error_codeEm+0x234)[0x46c774]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZN5boost4asio6detail14strand_service8dispatchINS1_7binder2INS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv10connectionRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENS5_5list3INS5_5valueINS_10shared_ptrIS9_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSK_ILi2EEEvEEEEESB_mEEEEvRPNS2_11strand_implET_+0xcd)[0x47216d]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZN5boost4asio6detail15wrapped_handlerINS0_10io_service6strandENS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv10connectionRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENS5_5list3INS5_5valueINS_10shared_ptrIS9_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSK_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEclISB_mEEvRKT_RKT0_+0xd9)[0x472439]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZN5boost4asio6detail18completion_handlerINS1_17rewrapped_handlerINS1_7binder2INS1_15wrapped_handlerINS0_10io_service6strandENS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv10connectionRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENS8_5list3INS8_5valueINS_10shared_ptrISC_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSN_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEESE_mEESV_EEE11do_completeEPNS1_15task_io_serviceEPNS1_25task_io_service_operationESG_m+0x1e5)[0x4726f5]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZN5boost4asio6detail14strand_service8dispatchINS1_17rewrapped_handlerINS1_7binder2INS1_15wrapped_handlerINS0_10io_service6strandENS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv10connectionRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENS9_5list3INS9_5valueINS_10shared_ptrISD_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSO_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEESF_mEESW_EEEEvRPNS2_11strand_implET_+0x2ad)[0x472aed]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZN5boost4asio6detail19asio_handler_invokeINS1_7binder2INS1_15wrapped_handlerINS0_10io_service6strandENS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv10connectionRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENS7_5list3INS7_5valueINS_10shared_ptrISB_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSM_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEESD_mEES6_SU_EEvRT_PNS4_IT0_T1_EE+0x15f)[0x472d3f]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZN5boost4asio6detail23reactive_socket_recv_opINS0_17mutable_buffers_1ENS1_15wrapped_handlerINS0_10io_service6strandENS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv10connectionRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENS7_5list3INS7_5valueINS_10shared_ptrISB_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSM_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEEE11do_completeEPNS1_15task_io_serviceEPNS1_25task_io_service_operationESF_m+0xce)[0x472ede]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZN5boost4asio6detail15task_io_service3runERNS_6system10error_codeE+0x79a)[0x47ceea]
./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZN5boost4asio10io_service3runEv+0x25)[0x47d1d5]
/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.48.0(+0xdda9)[0x7fbbdecd4da9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a)[0x7fbbdd42ee9a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fbbdd737cbd]
```

The line `./UpdateServer/build/UpdateServer(_ZNSt6vectorISsSaISsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsS1_EERKSs+0x111)[0x476521]`

seems to demangle to std::vector insert iterator, which is why I believe my program is crashing on the shared vector insert(I do not believe I have any other vectors of strings in my program), however I am fairly positive I am using my vector in a safe way, on both the insert and the read.

So I guess my question is when I am pushing information onto a shared vector, are there race condition problems I have to worry about that would cause my crash?  And is the approach I am taking a feasible approach, or should I rethink my design in someway?  Please let me know if you need any more information, I will be glad to provide anything I can.

Thank you

Comment: Is `shared_queue` of type `vector<std::string>`?

Comment: Opps, sorry about that, yes it is.  And the shared queue in the request_handler and sig_handler are the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std` data structures are not thread safe ([for the most part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456012/507606)) and therefore require additional synchronization if accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.  In your case, one thread could be calling `push_back` while another thread is calling `erase`.  This will produce *undefined behavior*.  To fix this, both the `push_back` and the `erase` need to be protected by the same lock.  I recommend you google for thread safety in the c++ standard library and read more about it.

---

Also, using a `vector` here is probably not the best choice.  You should look into [std::queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) instead.  When you `erase` the first element of the `vector` is has to copy all of the strings later in the vector down one, which can be very expensive.  `queue` does not suffer from this problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely give this a shot, sounds like it is probably the solution, and good to know about queues, I'll switch my vector over too that.