# Are std::map and std::vector thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, stdvector, stdmap

I am developing a multi threaded application, each thread will read (there will be no modifying of structures) from a group of maps and vectors. Can anyone please advise, since the threads are only reading from these structures would it be necessary to implement a sharable mutex around the code blocks where these structures are being read?

Comment: Related question and answers here on SO: [C++11 STL containers and thread safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931787/c11-stl-containers-and-thread-safety).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In case of read only map/vector there is no need to use mutexes.
This was already answered for both [vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455982/is-stl-vector-concurrent-read-thread-safe) and [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846186/thread-safety-of-stdmap-for-read-only-operations)
While C++03 doesn't mention threads, C++11 has clause covering you question.

### 23.2.2 Container data races [container.requirements.dataraces]

> 1 For purposes of avoiding data races (17.6.5.9), implementations shall consider the following functions to be
> const: begin, end, rbegin, rend, front, back, data, find, lower_bound, upper_bound, equal_range, at
> and, except in associative or unordered associative containers, operator[].
> 2 Notwithstanding (17.6.5.9), implementations are required to avoid data races when the contents of the contained
> object in different elements in the same sequence, excepting `vector<bool>`, are modified concurrently.
> 3 [ Note: For a `vector<int>` x with a size greater than one, x[1] = 5 and *x.begin() = 10 can be executed
> concurrently without a data race, but x[0] = 5 and *x.begin() = 10 executed concurrently may result in
> a data race. As an exception to the general rule, for a vector < bool > y, y[0] = true may race with y[1]
> = true. —end note ]

Thus in C++11 it is allowed not only to read objects , but also allow concurrent modification of its different objects(but not container!), with exception for vector < bool >

Comment: and what about other class members? When would it be necessary to use  a shared mutex?

Comment: @godzilla once container is going to be modified, you will need to use mutex on both read and write. In case of immutable read only container it can be accessed from different threads concurrently.

Comment: Actually I think the standard doesn’t give any guarantees whatsoever. It certainly doesn’t for C++03, maybe it does for C++11. But no sane implementation would be thread unsafe in this scenario.

Comment: @KonradRudolph C++03 doesn't mention threads indeed, thru there is `23.2.2 Container data races` clause in C++ 11