# Concurrent write to different buckets in unordered_map (C++)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

C++ newbie here.  I'm trying to write to different buckets concurrently in an unordered_map.  From what I can tell by searching, it is my understanding that this should be a thread safe operation.  My (perhaps incorrect) understanding is based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846186/thread-safety-of-stdmap-for-read-only-operations) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130494/are-stdmap-and-stdvector-thread-safe), as well as the referenced portion of the C++11 standard (particularly item 2 -- emphasis mine):

> **23.2.2 Container data races [container.requirements.dataraces]**
>
> 1 For purposes of avoiding data races (17.6.5.9), implementations shall consider the following functions to be const: begin, end, rbegin, rend, front, back, data, find, lower_bound, upper_bound, equal_range, at and, except in associative or unordered associative containers, operator[].
>
> 2 Notwithstanding (17.6.5.9), **implementations are required to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in different elements in the same sequence, excepting `vector<bool>`, are modified concurrently**.
>
> 3 [ Note: For a vector x with a size greater than one, x[1] = 5 and *x.begin() = 10 can be executed concurrently without a data race, but x[0] = 5 and *x.begin() = 10 executed concurrently may result in a data race. As an exception to the general rule, for a vector < bool > y, y[0] = true may race with y[1] = true. —end note ]

In any case, it seems that writing to different buckets is not thread safe with the standard containers, as demonstrated by the code below. You'll see that I enable a lock corresponding to the bucket being modified before writing, yet sometimes  pairs do not get recorded correctly.  For what it's worth, if I use a single lock -- e.g., just change `auto bkt = mm->bucket(key);` to `auto bkt=0;`, effectively locking the entire unordered_map container -- everything works as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

#define NUM_LOCKS 409
#define N 100
#define NUM_THREADS 2

using namespace std;


class SpinLock
{
    public:
        void lock()
        {
            while(lck.test_and_set(memory_order_acquire)){}
        }
    void unlock()
        {
            lck.clear(memory_order_release);
        }

    private:
        atomic_flag lck = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
};


vector<SpinLock> spinLocks(NUM_LOCKS);


void add_to_map(unordered_map<int,int> * mm, const int keyStart, const int keyEnd, const int tid){

    for(int key=keyStart;key<keyEnd;++key){
        auto bkt = mm->bucket(key);

        //lock bucket
        spinLocks[bkt].lock();

        //insert pair
        mm->insert({key,tid});

        //unlock bucket
        spinLocks[bkt].unlock();
    }

}


int main() {

    int Nbefore, Nafter;
    thread *t = new thread[NUM_THREADS];

    //create an unordered map, and reserve enough space to avoid a rehash
    unordered_map<int,int> my_map;
    my_map.reserve(2*NUM_THREADS*N);

    //count number of buckets to make sure that a rehash didn't occur
    Nbefore=my_map.bucket_count();


    // Launch NUM_THREADS threads.  Thread k adds keys k*N through (k+1)*N-1 to the hash table, all with associated value = k.

    for(int threadID=0;threadID<NUM_THREADS;++threadID){
        t[threadID]=thread(add_to_map,&my_map,threadID*N,(threadID+1)*N,threadID);
    }

    // Wait for the threads to finish
    for(int threadID=0;threadID<NUM_THREADS;++threadID){
        t[threadID].join();
    }

    //count number of buckets to make sure that a rehash didn't occur
    Nafter=my_map.bucket_count();


    cout << "Number of buckets before adding elements: " << Nbefore <<endl;
    cout << "Number of buckets after  adding elements: " << Nafter  << " <--- same as above, so rehash didn't occur" <<endl;

    //see if any keys are missing
    for(int key=0;key<NUM_THREADS*N;++key){

        if(!my_map.count(key)){

            cout << "key " << key << " not found!" << endl;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program will exit when a key was erroneously not entered.  A sample output is:

```
Number of buckets before adding elements: 401
Number of buckets after  adding elements: 401 <--- same as above, so rehash didn't occur
key 0 not found!
key 91 not found!
key 96 not found!
key 97 not found!
key 101 not found!
key 192 not found!
key 193 not found!
key 195 not found!
```

So, my question is two-fold:

1. Am I doing something wrong in how I am locking the buckets?
2. If so, is there a better way to lock the map on a bucket-by-bucket basis to enable concurrent writes to different buckets?

Finally, I'll mention that I already tried TBB's concurrent_unordered_map, but it was much slower in my application than simply doing things in serial.  The stray errors aside, my bucket-locking approach using std::unordered_map performed significantly better.

Comment: this is the proper way to ask a question! research, code, errors, and how you tried fixing it! Most new users should read this.  +1

Comment: Your code has UB, of course, as you've probably figured out, since your calls of `insert` cause a data race. A simple failure mode in a real implementation is for example in libc++ where `insert` increments the size count, so you have a race on the size variable. But just look at your own library implementation and notice the ways in which it is not thread-safe.

Comment: Yes,as you show us:implementations shall consider the following functions to be const: begin, end, rbegin, rend, front, back, data, find, lower_bound, upper_bound, equal_range...So reading is thread safe,but write not...like Kerrek SB says.

Comment: I agree with @KerrekSB's comment that `insert` causes UB in this case (motivating the original question). However, I disagree with Ron's oversimplification that writing is not thread safe.  Ron has ignored 2. & 3. of the referenced standard which mandates races be avoided when _different_ elements of the container are _modified_ concurrently.  So, writing is safe provided threads are synchronized to not simultaneously write in the same location.  So, it would seem locks on a bucket-by-bucket basis would be sufficient, but it's apparently not. @KerrekSB, how do I look at libc++ implementation?

Comment: @Tom Thank you for the explanation, the write operation is not guaranteed thread-safe,but not all write operations are not thread-safe. There are open-source GNU libc implementation, you could refer to.

Comment: Adding an element is not the same as modifying an element. Buckets are not elements of an unordered set/map -- elements are key/value pairs.  You are adding elements, and I don't see a guarantee for that being safe?

Comment: I see your point.  I was envisioning that an unordered_map was essentially a vector of lists (one list per bucket).  So, editing separate buckets concurrently would be thread safe.  However, your comment makes clear that "element" is the operative word here.  I've been trying to find implementation details, but can only find [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01103_source.html) which doesn't seem to contain specific details about how things are implemented.  Sorry if I am looking in the wrong place, am totally new to C++ and am learning as I go.

Comment: @Tom: I think you're misunderstanding the statement in the standard. As Yakk expained, the meaning is that you can modify different container *elements* concurrently. You are never allowed to modify the container itself concurrently, and "modify" means calling any non-const member function (see Ron's comment). You can make assumptions about the implementation all day long, but that doesn't buy you any standard guarantees.

Comment: @Tom: Open the header file of interest in an editor.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of a container are not the buckets, but rather the `value_type` elements.

Modifying one element in a `std` container has no concurrency impact on other elements.  But modifying one *bucket* has no such guarantee.

Adding or removing elements in a bucket is a non-`const` operation on the container that is not from the special list of non-`const` operations that are safe to use without synchronization.